# Ember link-to Set Active Class Immediately

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a nav bar that has special CSS that shows up when a link has the `"active"` class on it. It looks something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>{{link-to "routeName"}}<i class="icon-up"></i>{{/link-to}}</li>
    {{!-- more list items like the previous one... --}}
</ul>
```

However, when I click on the link with `"routeName"`, a rather expensive query is made that may be slow at times. I have a `LoadingRoute` set up with a loading view that consists of a simple spinner, but it seems like the link does not receive the `"active"` class until the route's promise is resolved. Is there a Handlebars-friendly way to tell `link-to` to immediately set the `"active"` class when it is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that the URL does not get updated until the end of a transition. Thanks to the peeps in the Ember IRC and Machty, this is an issue that has been resolved and will be in the next beta cycle.

- The fix: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4122
- The beta cycle "go" progress: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4052

Comment: It looks like the URL is now updated immediately, but the `active` class still is not applied immediately. Were you able to figure out a solution for this?