# Ember LinkView apply "active" class immediately

Tags: ember.js

When clicking a link in Ember (or beginning a transition through some other means), the URL updates immediately. I would also like for the "active" class to be immediately applied to any matching `LinkView`s, rather than waiting until after the transition completes. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420098/ember-link-to-set-active-class-immediately) asked the same thing and is answered, but the proposed solution doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently not an easy way to do this. However [there is an issue on the GitHub repo for it](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4908).